# In "The Passage", why do the Raptors need to see the civilian ships?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

In the episode "The Passage" of *Battlestar Galactica*, the Raptors are guiding civilian ships through a nebula. The civilian ships can't navigate so need military escorts to guide them.

Several ships are lost because the Raptors lose visual contact with them. Yet they relay navigation information by radio. If the radio works, why do they need to see the ships?

Comment: There was a ton of interference from the radiation in the corridor. There could have been radio loss,  or to mention the radio could have failed and then what would you do? The risk would have been too great not to use visual sight since only the Raptors were radiation-hardened.

Answer (score 3):

The science of jumping is pretty soft, so it behaves the way it's needed to in each episode.

Prior to starting the crossings, Sharon notes that due to the light and instrument interference, ships tend to drift. They don't specify why that's suddenly a problem, but in the mission briefing Apollo makes it clear that one of the duties of the Raptors is to stop the ships from drifting prior to jumping.

> Apollo: You heard. Five round trips. o­n our outbound jumps we’ll each be responsible for relaying jump coordinates to our own specific civilian ship, nailing them to their jump points, and insuring they don’t drift off.

The visual contact appears to be necessary to make sure they are in the right place for the jump (or that the jump is correctly calculated for their starting point).

Comment: I guess they could be using inertial navigation to track drift and compensate for it. Visual range is enough to guarantee they are close enough for the error to be within the acceptable margin. You would think that the lost ships would just jump anyway, after all they have nothing to lose at that point.

Comment: You'd think, but I guess plot > science